# Simple JQuery Validator addMethod not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

**Updated question on the bottom**

I am trying to validate a super simple form. Eventually the username will be compared to a RegExp statement and the same will go for the password. However right now I am just trying to learn the Validator addMethod format.

I currently have this script:

```
JQuery.validator.addMethod(
    "legalName",
    function(value, element) {
        if (element.value == "bob")
        {
            return false;
        }
        else return true;
    },
    "Use a valid username."
);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
            username: {
                legalName: true
            }
        },
    });
});
```

Which if I am not mistaken should return false and respond with "Use a valid username." if I were to put "bob" into the form.

However, it is simply submitting it.

I am linking to JQuery BEFORE Validator in the header like instructed.

My uber simple form looks like this:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
  <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Username *</span><input type="text" name="username" /></div>
  <div class="form-row"><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
</form>
```

Finally how would I go about restructing the addMethod function to return true `if` and `false` at the `else` stage while keeping the message alert for a `false` return?
(ignore this last part if you don't understand what I was trying to say :) )

Thanks in advance.

---

Thank to everyone who pointed out my `JQuery` -> `jQuery` typo.

**New** -> [RegEx in jQuery Validator addMethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230332/regex-in-jquery-validator-addmethod)

Ideally, I am trying to turn this into a simple login form (username/password). It is for demonstration only so it wont have a database attached or anything, just some simple js validations. I am looking to make the username validate for <48 characters, only english letters and numbers, no special characters. I thought a whitelist would be easiest so I had something like this: `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*${1,48}` but I am not sure if that is proper JS RegExp (it varies from Ruby RegExp if I am not mistaken?...Usually I use rubular.com). Password will be similar but require some upper/lowercase and numbers.

I believe I need to make another `$.validator.addMethod` for `legalPassword` that will look very similar.

**Edit**

changed the regexp to `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` and added `maxlength: 48` to my validate function. However the regexp is still not working and as far as i can tell it is correct.

Comment: use `jQuery`( small `j` ) not `JQuery` (capital)

Comment: Thanks to everyone who mentioned the case-sensitive typo! I will try to explain the second part a little better now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `JQuery`, not `jQuery` (little `j`).

JavaScript is case sensitive...

```
>>> typeof jQuery
"function"
>>> typeof JQuery
"undefined"
```

If `$` points to your `jQuery` object too (it does by default), then you can just use it.

As for your custom validation function, you could make that terser like so...

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
    "legalName",
    function(value, element) {
        return (element.value != "bob");
    },
    "Use a valid username."
);
```

For a case insensitive comparison, use `toLowerCase()` on the `value` first.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and being able to decipher the second part! I added a further question if you care to look at it.

Comment: @tehaaron You will get better exposure by posting a new question :)

Comment: This is true...and you can get another answered question that way ;) haha

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the first part simply by changing `JQuery.validator.addMethod` to `$.validator.addMethod`.

I don't totally understand your second question. If you describe the behavior you're interested in achieving, maybe I can help you get there.

Comment: Thanks, I added another question on the bottom, if you care to have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("legalname", function(value, element) {
    var i = /^bob$/i;
    return (!(i.test(value)));
}, "Invalid user name");
```

see the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7xD2H/3/)**