# RegEx in jQuery Validator addMethod

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I need a few RegEx for my jQuery validator custom methods. The first which I thought was going to be easy was just limiting a username to only US letters, numbers, and no special characters. I came up with `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe it is due to the way it appears in the function:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "legalName",
    function(value, element) {
        return (element.value != "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    },
    "Use a valid username."
);
```

The second is validating the password which is essentially the same limitations with the addition of a required number of certain characters such as an uppercase, number, ect. I figure once I get the username RegEx down the password wont be too hard, just a matter of fitting in `{1}`'s and such within the expression.

The last part of my question is how do I add a second method ("legalPassword") inside of the original `.addMethod` or do I need a create a whole other `$.validator.addMethod`?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
            username: {
                legalName: true,
                required: true,
                maxlength: 35
            }
        },
    });
});
```

and the table code:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
  <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Username *</span><input type="text" name="username" /></div>
  <div class="form-row"><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
</form>
```

New code (still not working):

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "legalName",
    function(value, element) {
        /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test( value );
    },
    "Use a valid username."
);
```

Comment: You should never put **ANY** restrictions on passwords (except a minimum length, multiple types of characters, etc)! As you are (hopefully) storing them as a hash there is no good reason to do so anyway.

Comment: I am not storing anything, its simply for demonstration and won't even be validated for a database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test( value );`

Answer (score 2):

Try using the Regex.test function instead to do the check against your string.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test( element.value );
```

See here for more info: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev3.shtml

Comment: I tried replacing `return (element.value != "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");` with `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test( element.value );` but now it is returning false on both legal and nonlegal usernames.

Comment: Does element.value contain the expected value? Try testing your regex using a hardcoded string to make sure it is OK. Regex looks OK to me. Your function takes (value, element) yet you are testing element.value, is that correct?

Comment: According to the tests the RegEx is working fine. As for the second part...I think yes? haha I am still pretty new to js/jquery. I added the rest of the code I have written myself for both the form validation and form html if it helps at all.

Comment: I would try testing against the value parameter instead of the element. Try: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test( value )

Comment: I solved it by looking at the validator source and mimicking their code. `return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test( value );` If you want to change your original post I will mark it as the answer since you helped me get to this point and each change brought it closer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex Mask Plugin

Browse the following link

[regexMask()](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/regex)

Comment: Thanks, but I would prefer to learn how to get this working without another plugin.